# Webpack-dev-server fails to compile the same source as Webpack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to configure `webpack-dev-server`, but keep getting the error

```
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

What's strange is that I can successfully compile with just `webpack`.  Here's the output from both:

**Webpack-dev-server**

```
> app-react@1.0.0 web-dev E:\App.React
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --progress --colors

[17:42:21] developer mode: enabled
[17:42:21] Beta release: false
 10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active
Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
webpack output is served from /                                                                                                                      10% building modules 4/7 modules 3 active ...eact\node_modules\strip-ansi\index.js
[at-loader] Using typescript@2.4.1 from typescript and "tsconfig.json" from E:\App.React/tsconfig.json.
                                                                                                            94% asset optimization
[at-loader] Checking started in a separate process...

[at-loader] Checking finished with 3 errors                                                                                                                            Hash: a94bf08b4d38bcd62009
Version: webpack 2.2.1
Time: 5372ms
        Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    bundle.js  1.71 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
bundle.js.map  2.09 MB       0  [emitted]         main
chunk    {0} bundle.js, bundle.js.map (main) 1.67 MB [entry] [rendered]
  [223] ./~/reactxp/index.js 146 bytes {0} [built]
  [239] ./src/ts/index.tsx 248 bytes {0} [built]
  [240] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 5.59 kB {0} [built]
  [241] ./~/ansi-html/index.js 4.26 kB {0} [built]
  [242] ./~/ansi-regex/index.js 135 bytes {0} [built]
  [243] ./src/ts/arena/TempTDP.tsx 2.6 kB {0} [built]
  [244] ./src/ts/platform/web/PlatformModules.ts 414 bytes {0} [built]
  [262] ./~/html-entities/index.js 231 bytes {0} [built]
  [564] ./~/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {0} [built]
  [566] ./~/url/url.js 23.3 kB {0} [built]
  [567] ./~/url/util.js 314 bytes {0} [built]
  [571] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.6 kB {0} [built]
  [572] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 856 bytes {0} [built]
  [574] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 77 bytes {0} [built]
  [575] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/ts/index.tsx 40 bytes {0} [built]
     + 561 hidden modules

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/ts/index.tsx:5:30
    TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'null'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/ts/platform/native-common/NativeLogger.ts:1:31
    TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native'. 'E:/App.React/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/react-native` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-native';`

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/typings/react.d.ts:112:11
    TS2559: Type 'Component<P, S>' has no properties in common with type 'ComponentLifecycle<P, S>'.
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

**Webpack**

```
> app-react@1.0.0 web-watch E:\App.React
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --progress --colors --watch

[17:46:04] developer mode: enabled
[17:46:04] Beta release: false
  0% compiling
Webpack is watching the files…
                                                                                                                                                                                 10% building modules 0/1 modules 1 active ....js!E:\App.React\src\ts\index.tsx
[at-loader] Using typescript@2.4.1 from typescript and "tsconfig.json" from E:\App.React/tsconfig.json.
                                                                                                            94% asset optimization
[at-loader] Checking started in a separate process...

[at-loader] Checking finished with 3 errors                                                                                                                            Hash: c0ddf8dd298d85956a54
Version: webpack 2.2.1
Time: 4495ms
        Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    bundle.js  1.41 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
bundle.js.map  1.73 MB       0  [emitted]         main
   [3] ./~/reactxp/dist/common/Interfaces.js 9.04 kB {0} [built]
   [5] ./~/react/react.js 56 bytes {0} [built]
  [13] ./~/reactxp/dist/common/Types.js 8.78 kB {0} [built]
  [14] ./~/reactxp/dist/web/Styles.js 15.3 kB {0} [built]
 [119] ./~/reactxp/dist/web/ViewBase.js 8.94 kB {0} [built]
 [121] ./~/reactxp/index.js 146 bytes {0} [built]
 [198] ./~/reactxp/dist/web/Accessibility.js 1.07 kB {0} [built]
 [199] ./~/reactxp/dist/web/Image.js 14.1 kB {0} [built]
 [202] ./~/reactxp/dist/web/Text.js 4.71 kB {0} [built]
 [203] ./~/reactxp/dist/web/TextInput.js 8.3 kB {0} [built]
 [207] ./src/ts/arena/TempTDP.tsx 2.6 kB {0} [built]
 [208] ./src/ts/platform/web/PlatformModules.ts 414 bytes {0} [built]
 [209] ./src/ts/platform/web/WebLogger.ts 600 bytes {0} [built]
 [478] ./~/reactxp/dist/web/ReactXP.js 5.47 kB {0} [built]
 [494] ./src/ts/index.tsx 248 bytes {0} [built]
    + 480 hidden modules

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/ts/index.tsx:5:30
    TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'null'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/ts/platform/native-common/NativeLogger.ts:1:31
    TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native'. 'E:/App.React/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/react-native` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-native';`

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/typings/react.d.ts:112:11
    TS2559: Type 'Component<P, S>' has no properties in common with type 'ComponentLifecycle<P, S>'.
```

I'm using `webpack@2.2.1` and `webpack-dev-server@2.5.1`.  I have tried other versions but still get the same problem.

Would those errors cause `webpack-dev-server` to fail, but not `webpack`?

Here's my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const webpackConfig: webpack.Configuration = {
  entry: "./src/ts/index.tsx",

  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/build/web",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },

  // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
  devtool: "source-map",

  resolve: {
    // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
    extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
    alias: {
      PlatformModules: path.resolve(
        __dirname,
        "src/ts/platform/web/PlatformModules"
      )
    }
  },

  module: {
    loaders: isDev
      ? [{ test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" }]
      : [
          { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },
          {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            loader: "webpack-unassert-loader",
            enforce: "post"
          }
        ]
  }
};

export default webpackConfig;
```

I also can't seem to find any info online on how to debug these types of issues.  Is there no `--verbose` equivalent?

Comment: I believe you should start from fixing 3 errors, which are reported by both commands and start from `ERROR`.

Comment: how are you defining `isDev` ?

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin - I'll work on those errors.  It would be strange (?) if they were failing `webpack-dev-server` and not `webpack`, no?

Comment: @Bulkan - I'm using NODE_ENV for that.  If I remove all references to `isDev`, it doesn't change anything

Comment: No. The error message about failed compilation just indicates, that build was completed with errors. Depending on configuration it may still work in dev-server as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your webpack log:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/ts/index.tsx:5:30
    TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'null'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/ts/platform/native-common/NativeLogger.ts:1:31
    TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native'. 'E:/App.React/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/react-native` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-native';`

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/typings/react.d.ts:112:11
    TS2559: Type 'Component<P, S>' has no properties in common with type 'ComponentLifecycle<P, S>'.
```

You can see that `webpack` is failing too. Fix these errors and both (webpack and webpack-dev-server) will work.

Comment: `webpack` builds the bundle.js exactly as I'd expect, so I don't think it's 'failing'.

Comment: But you're probably right, I'll fix these issues and see if that helps.  I'm new to this, so just assumed that it was working despite those errors (since the bundle.js is built).